# Garbage collection takes a very long time in Internet Explorer after building a large table with ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, garbage-collection

I am building a large table (3,000+ rows) with the ng-repeat directive from AngularJS (1.2.26). The data is a very simple array of arrays of time and temperature `[[time, temperature], [time, temperature], ...]`.

This is how the data is displayed in a table (using [Slim templating](http://slim-lang.com/)):

```
  table.table.table-bordered
    thead
      tr
        th.time.first-child= t('Time')
        th.temperature.sensor
    tbody
      tr[bindonce ng-repeat="item in readings"]
        td.datetime
          span.date bo-text="formatDate(item.time)"
          span.time bo-html="formatTime(item.time)"
        td bo-text="item.reading.temperature | number: 2"
```

As you can see, we are using the [bind once](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) library to reduce the number of angular watchers. This is a report so we don't need to uphold data binding.

Loading the data and rendering the report takes about ~4 seconds on Chrome or Firefox and ~8 seconds on Internet Explorer (11). However, after the table is built on internet explorer, the browser will take up to two minutes performing Garbage Collection (according to the UI Responsiveness tab).

I need more "reputation" to post pictures, so I'll try to describe what is happening as best I can.

The whole table rendering process occurs as a result of the `xhr.onreadystatechange` event listener (which has since been removed from angular in 1.3). Each row and span are added to the table with `appendChild()` -> `insertBefore()` functions from jQuery or the `innerHTML` function from the browser. These happen thousands of times and account for the ~8 seconds that I mentioned before. Once these are completed, these are immediately followed by a few lines of garbage collection that, in total, take well over 60 seconds.

In absence of a picture of the output, this is a list of the time at which the execution started after the last `appendChild()`, followed by the total execution time (the length of the bar in the window).

1. 0.24 s, 0.0065 ms
2. 0.36 s, 13.83 ms
3. 0.85 s, 0.31 ms
4. 10 s, 0.0042 ms
5. 57 s, 25.54 ms
6. 60 s, 0.048 ms

Then, there is another gap of about 10 s before the rest of the process proceeds.

I don't understand what is happening here, because each individual garbage collection is very short, but the gap between them is very long. I don't know much about garbage collection in the browsers, so that my be hindering my understanding. This is not happening in Chrome or Firefox.

I've followed various guides about analyzing memory profiling. I do not believe there is a memory leak. Again, I can't add more links because of my reputation, but I followed the Chrome one titled "JavaScript Memory Profiling" and the IE one titled "Improving UI Responsiveness".

There is another piece of this that I'm not sure if it is relevant or not, but I'll mention it here in case it is. When you run a profiling session during this delay, IE says that the delay is during the requestAnimationFrame `https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/raf.js#L15` function of AngularJS `$$RAFProvider`. This may be related to the fact that AngularJS fires an "enter" event for every row added via ng-repeat. I've been trying to disable that animation event without luck so far.

Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be very much appreciated. Specifically, it would be great if I could add a breakpoint on the garbage collection to see what is going on, but I don't think I could do that.

Comment: Are you accounting for the browser layout time of your table?  Large tables can take awhile to layout.  How do you know what time is taken by garbage collection vs. other things going on in the browser?

Comment: I believe I am, yes. I've been looking at the "UI Responsiveness" tab of the IE dev tools, essentially analogous to the Timeline in Chrome. I can see the sequential rendering of each table row and table data in that tab over time. Once all of that is finished, then the long garbage collection starts. Since it takes only ~5 seconds in Chrome and Firefox, I don't think it is simply the browser creating the table.

Comment: Do you *really* need to show all 3000 rows at the same time? If not, can use pagination/scroll updating. Could also look into ui-grid which works quite well for this many rows.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the garbage collection has a number of very sparse spikes over 60 seconds. Why is this even a problem?

Comment: @reptilicus, as I understand it we originally showed all 3000 rows because the performance wasn't bad. I suggested using pagination/infinite scrolling yesterday and we may go that route if we can't figure it out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @NewDev it is a problem because it holds up anything else from happening. The page doesn't finish it's last style calculations and is completely unresponsive until the garbage collection stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much investigation, I *think* I figured out what the problem is, or at least a potential problem.

The table I was rendering had two columns - time and temperature. The time column had two `<span>` elements. So, for each row, Angular was marking the element for the "enter" animation as it does for every element of an `ng-repeat`. As part of the Angular animation process, Angular requests an animation frame from the browser via the [$RAFProvider](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/raf.js). When I profiled the process in Internet Explorer and viewed the call stack, this is where the huge delay was. I originally thought that wasn't the issue, but after a ton of troubleshooting I've come to think that the Internet Explorer requestAnimationFrame method just can't handle ~9000 calls nearly as quickly as Chrome or Firefox.

To get around the issue, I chose to implement [ngInfiniteScroll](http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html) and it is working very well. We are generating the full, 3,000 line report via a different code path if the user really wants the full report.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and came to the same conclusion after running profiles across the the major browsers. Since I can't seem to convince the client that paging + an arsenal of searching, sorting, etc... is the better approach, looks like I'm in the same boat as you. I am using [angular-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll) to resolve this although I am running into some issues - will update this thread if I get it working.

Comment: I looked at ngInfiniteScroll, but I'm not sure it cleans up the DOM (I'm not sure it removes elements from the DOM that are no longer visible?) Angular-Virutal-Scroll is specific to ng-repeat, but that's what I like about it - it takes advantage of the fact that ng-repeat filters will do the heavy lifting of removing filtered-out elements from the DOM - see parts I and II of this blog post for more details: [angularjs-virtual-scrolling-part-I](http://blog.stackfull.com/2013/02/angularjs-virtual-scrolling-part-1/)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link @Martin. I'll check that out next time I need to implement an infinite scroll.

Comment: np there's also https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat - neither of these worked for me, however, so I had to roll my own

Answer (score 0):

For ng-repeat, angular will create a scope for every item in repeat for the two way binding. But in your code, it is not necessary, you just display the data.

If you are using above angularjs 1.3.x, you can use binging-once feature, then no those scope will be created.

I am not familiar with that template. But you use 'bindonce' in TR, if it is 'bindonce' in angularjs, I think you should use 1.3.x version.

And another problem is:

```
span.date bo-text="formatDate(item.time)"
```

You use a function for the data format. And as the problem above, you should use 'bind-once'. If you use js, it is:

```
<span>{{::formatDate(item.time)}}</span>
```

Add '::' for binding once.

If you don't add bind once, when you scroll over the table, the format function for same item will be called many times. So for the format, you should use date filter like:

```
<span>{{item.time | date: 'yyyy/MM/DD'}}</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are still on 1.2.26, but there are a few things we want in 1.3 now so maybe this will be the final push. For your comment about bind-once, since we are using the third party library, the syntax is that `bo-` at the beginning of the attribute as you see with `bo-text`. Or are you saying the problem is with the formatDate() function?